# Where to find Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I am trying to create a Kendo Scheduler, but you need to pass in a model. In the examples it tells you to use:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Scheduler.TaskViewModel>())
```

But of course I don't have this view model. Can someone tell me where I can find it?

Answer (score 7):

The models referenced in the KendoUI for ASP.NET MVC examples are not part of the `Kendo.Mvc.dll` assembly. Instead, you must download them from your Telerik account. Go to [telerik.com](http://www.telerik.com) and sign in. From there, navigate to your Products & Subscriptions and locate  "KendoUI for ASP.NET MVC" and select "Browse all product files". Download the "Manual Installation" file and unzip it.

[image]

You'll find the examples (and the referenced models) in the `wrappers\aspnetmvc\Examples` folder.

[image]

If you want to reference the models in your project, just grab a copy of the compiled assembly `Kendo.Mvc.Examples.dll` from the bin folder of the example project. Keep in mind this will include everything from the examples (controllers, models, view-models, etc.).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Your model simply has to implement `ISchedulerEvent`.

An example of one of mine is below:

```
public class AvailableDateModel : ISchedulerEvent
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string StartTimezone { get; set; }
    public string EndTimezone { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update to @Kevin Babcock's answer.

To view the Telerik example models:

1. Log in to your Telerik account.
2. Click on Downloads.
3. Click on Progress Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC
4. Under Other Setup Files, click on telerik.ui.for.aspnetmvc.[release].commercial.zip.
5. Extract and navigate to: wrappers\aspnetmvc\examples\MVC5\
6. Open the Kendo.Mvc.Examples.sln or browse the Kendo.Mvc.Examples folder to find the model you're looking for.